# The requested URL/was not found on this server - google/explorer, external connects

Tags: apache, wamp, external, firewall, router

I have tried about 66 sites, several questions on each site/blog, checked the apache guides, and I am not getting anywhere  :(

WAMP 2.4.9, Win 8, Web Expression 4

It works just fine on my localhost on this computer only. I want to get it to work on external sites.  I have the green server icon, no errors in cmd, my localhost works from the base PC, my website can be access from the base PC. However, after scrolling through many sites, I still have the issue of not being able to access the website from other computers. I created the rule for firewall, I tried turning off Kapersky/allowing exceptions, I tried everything. I was thinking that my ISP may be blocking the port 80, but i tried 8080 and that didnt work either. I did port forwarding, revised my SQL and PHP configs so that they allow all from localhost, etc. (which I turned back because I didnt think that was the issue and security concern). Anybody have more ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you! Riggs fixed it. yay!! turns out it was a redirect of the domain towards my ip that was needed.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer assuming you have port forwarded your router correctly is

```
left click wampmanager -> Put Online
```

This changes the httpd.conf file and therefore Apache to allow access from any IP address. By default WAMPServer, being primarily a developer tool and not a live web server environment, is configured for your safety to allow access only from the PC running WAMPServer.

Comment: I have it online.  I am trying to setup a website for my students

Comment: No.  Wampserver is online, but outside of my computer I cannot access my webpage :(

Comment: How are you trying to access the web server i.e. what are you entering in the url on the browser when you are accessing it from another location out on the internet

Comment: I have a domain.  When I enter local host, I get a webpage.  When I enter my domain - my webpage only comes up on that wamp PC

Comment: Lets chat, I have setup a room at http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83847/discussion-between-riggsfolly-and-margo click the link you can join the conversation

Comment: Are you still there??

Comment: Look at your WAN ip address in your router admin page. Does it start with `10.x.y.z`

Comment: Do you see anything in the apache error log like `access denied by server configuration` also do you see any extenal ip addresses mentioned in the access log or error log?

Comment: Then you are not actually connecting to Apache. Are you sure your domain name is pointing to your WAN ip address?

Comment: how do you mean?  I put it into the hosts file.  sorry, i am self taught

Comment: The hosts file has **NOTHING** to do with external access. It only preloads the windows dns cache with `domain=ip` so only effects that specific PC where the HOSTS file exists i.e. the browser on the Apache PC. So what url are you using for an external browser url

Comment: you mean you want me to give you my domain?

Comment: We can chat on SKYPE if you want to keep this a secret

Comment: i have yahoo but dont have skype - interferes with port 80

Comment: Not if you [reconfigure it](http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,134129,134132#msg-134132) and not if you start it after you start Apache

Comment: i dont have time to install right now - have to go to work soon  :(

Comment: Post a question on `wampserver.com/en` I will offer to connect up with TeamViewer so we can solve this together if you like some other day

Comment: i will be back here at 6 pm central US time.

Comment: Thats midnight in the UK so I may have wandered up the little wooden hill to bed by then

Comment: do you want me to ask a question on wamp now

Comment: Yes, then you can send a `Private Message` with the TeamViewer ID and PASSWORD. We can try tomorrow around this time, if you like. Should only take 15-30 mins

Comment: you actually caught me at 430 AM with insomnia  ugh

Comment: ok - i added it there.  i will get online as early as possible when i get home today and see if you are still awake.. not sure if i will be up at 430 am tomorrow.  heya - thanks for helping me

Comment: And I replied, see you later